# Find all changesets in named branch where file "X" was modified (including merges)

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am looking for a way with TortoiseHg (or plain hg if no other possibility exists) to locate all the changes to a particular file.

I've tried using a revision set query:
`merge() and file("path/to/filename.cs")`
but that didn't get me what I'm looking for.  It returns an empty set.  I assume this is because `merge()` only returns merges, and `file()` only (appears to) returns non-merges, so the intersection is empty.

I've also tried `modifies(pattern)` but that doesn't appear sufficiently different from `file(pattern)` (looks to me like `file()` is the union of `adds()` and `modifies()`). `contains(pattern)` doesn't return any elements at all.

So, is it possible to get a list of changesets in which a particular file has been modified in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're running into the "how did my change get into this branch" problem.  When you merge a changeset into a branch, Mercurial doesn't record that as a change.  Instead, it makes a note that the merged changeset is now part of the destination branch.  The only time  a merge will show that a file was modified is if there was a merge conflict, which results in a new changeset.

Finding what merge brought a changeset into a branch is a two step process.  First, you have to find the changeset where the change you're interested in occurred.

```
 hg log -r "file('<PATTERN>')
```

Once you have that revision, find the first *descendant* changeset in the destination branch:

```
hg log -r "first(branch(<BRANCH>) and descendants(<REVISION>))"
```

Comment: thanks much.  Sometimes you just can't see the answer.  Despite any number of searches, I never came across this one.  I appreciate your reply, as well as the link to the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`hg log -r "branch(BRANCH) and file('PATTERN')"`

Revset also can be used and entered into Filter Tooolbar in THG Workbench

Answer (score 0):

```
hg log grep name_of_your_file
```

Does the trick for me in terms of finding all the change sets that have resulted in a change to a given file.  Of course if you would like something pretty:

```
thg log name_of_your_file
```